# Check value from Spark DataFrame column and do transformations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe consists of person, transaction_id & is_successful. The dataframe consists of duplicate values for person with different transaction_ids and is_successful will be `True/False` for each transaction.

I would like to derive a new dataframe which will have one record for each person which consists latest transaction_id of that person and populate `True` only if any of his transactions are successful.

```
val input_df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,1, "True"), (1,2, "False"), (2,1, "False"), (2,2, "False"), (2,3, "True"), (3,1, "False"), (3,2, "False"), (3,3, "False"))).toDF("person","transaction_id", "is_successful")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [person: int, transaction_id: int ... 1 more field]

input_df.show(false)
+------+--------------+-------------+
|person|transaction_id|is_successful|
+------+--------------+-------------+
|1     |1             |True         |
|1     |2             |False        |
|2     |1             |False        |
|2     |2             |False        |
|2     |3             |True         |
|3     |1             |False        |
|3     |2             |False        |
|3     |3             |False        |
+------+--------------+-------------+
```

Expected Df:

```
+------+--------------+-------------+
|person|transaction_id|is_successful|
+------+--------------+-------------+
|1     |2             |True         |
|2     |3             |True         |
|3     |3             |False        |
+------+--------------+-------------+
```

How can we derive the dataframe like above?

Comment: I think based on your logic, the final row should have a `is_successful` value of `False` since there were no successful transactions for person `3`

Comment: Yes... it should be False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the @ggordon's sql version of answer in dataframe version.

```
 input_df.groupBy("person")
    .agg(max("transaction_id").as("transaction_id"),
      when(max(when('is_successful === "True", 1)
               .otherwise(0)) > 0, "True")
        .otherwise("False").as("is_successful"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve this by grouping your dataframe on `person` and finding the `max` `transaction_id` and `max` `is_successful`

I've included an example below of how this may be achieved using spark sql.

First, I created a temporary view of your dataframe in order to access using spark sql, then run the following sql statement in spark sql.

```scala
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_df");

val result_df = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>");
```

The sql statement groups the data for each person before using `max` to determine the last transaction id and a combination of `max` (`sum` could be used with the same logic also) and case expressions to derive the `is_successful` value. The case expression is nested as I've converted `True` to a numeric value of `1` and `False` to `0` to leverage a numeric comparison. This is within an outer case expression which checks if the `max` value is `> 0` (i.e. any value was successful) before printing `True`/`False`.

```sql
SELECT
    person,
    MAX(transaction_id) as transaction_id,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(
            CASE 
                WHEN is_successful = 'True' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ) > 0 THEN 'True'
        ELSE 'False'
    END as is_successful
FROM
    input_df
GROUP BY
    person
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is below in spark sql

```
select person,max(transaction_id) as transaction_id,max(is_successful) as is_successful from <table_name> group by person
```

Leave the complex work to max operator.As per the max operation True will come over False.So if one of your person has three False and one True, max of that would be True.

Comment: Your query is missing the GROUP BY and assumes the string values for is_successful will always be treated the same as boolean values throughout versions.